# Iteratively hide the last column of a html table using css/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to modify a table created by xx user through Sharepoint with responsive design in mind.  What I want to do is iteratively hide the last visible column in the table based on the width of the screen.

For example: a user creates a 10-column table and the max screen size is 1200.  If they minimize the window to 600px, then the last 5 columns should not be shown.  If they minimize the window to 800px, then the last 3 columns should not be shown.

Currently I can selectively remove columns with CSS using display:none on the :nth-child, but that doesn't account for whether or not the display is already set to none in order to move on to the n-1-child.

Is there a way to do this with CSS, or is this concept limited to Javascript?  And if so, how?

Thank you.

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` :)

Comment: overflow:hidden would only work if the OP was willing to chop off a column in the middle, rather than show full columns only.  And media queries would only work if the OP knows in advance the width of the columns.  @Stoic Developer - can you clarify your constraints?

Comment: @andi, essentially I cannot directly change the table; every alternation must be done through CSS or javascript.  And this has to account for any table a user creates with n columns.

Comment: @Morpheus `overflow:hidden;` does not seem practical with responsive design towards dynamic tables.

Comment: @drip I am already using media queries (responsive design) to determine when to remove each column from a table.

Comment: @Stoic Developer - can you post a fiddle with what you already have?

Comment: @andi, http://jsfiddle.net/lazyhermit/tcvB6/
I have found a small alternative using CSS (and you can see it in action through jsfiddle) but I feel like there can be something better or at least more reliable.

And there is another problem I have come across if I were to continue with CSS, I don't know how to stop it at the first or nth-column for individual tables.

Comment: I think you are going to need JS - are you OK with that?

Comment: @andi, I do not have a problem with that.  I would have preferred CSS, but I know it can't handle everything.  Do you have any suggestions where I can start or have come across a situation similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tcvB6/1/  Here's one possibility. I didn't set it to continually update if the screen size is changed, but you could add that in.  I wrapped the tables in a couple of divs to help the CSS, and then added this function:

```
$("table").each(function(){
    var $table = $(this);
    while ($table.outerWidth() > $("#wrapOuter").outerWidth()) {
        $table.find("tr").each(function(){
            $(this).find("td:visible, th:visible").last().hide();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Much appreciated.  Don't know if it will work till next week.  But that last line seems to be the key I was looking for.

Comment: For whatever reason, I can't get your concept to work out using jsfiddle (I do have jQuery 1.9.0 framework selected).  Additionally, testing the table's width isn't feasible with responsive design as there is no fixed container width.  Everything is measured in percentages with respect to the body.

Comment: You can test the table's width even without a fixed container width.  I'm not sure what isn't working out for you - can you publish your fiddle and I'll take a look?

Comment: Sorry about that last part.  I must have skimmed over your initial response and missed your explanation about the limits of the code.

Should the code be doing anything?  I am expanding and collapsing the on your jsfiddle result block, but none of the cells are disappearing.

Comment: Make sure to hit "run" each time you expand or collapse the results pane, so it refreshes.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've decided to stick with CSS and write some overlapping styles.  But I will keep your code in mind for the future.